# How to use pdf.js lib to fill xfa pdf forms?

Tags: pdf.js

I finally found a lib(pdf.js) that can open and read xfa forms. However I’m not been able to fill the fields, save them and download the new pdf.
Does anyone have an example on how to do it?
Tks

Tried to find some examples, but they didn't work.

Draft of the code:

```
  const pdfDocument = await pdfjs.getDocument({...source,
    enableXfa: true,
  }).promise;
  
  if (pdfDocument.allXfaHtml) {
    setFormType('xfa');
    setInputs(getAllInputs(pdfDocument.allXfaHtml));
    setOutput(JSON.stringify(pdfDocument.allXfaHtml, null, 2));

    pdfDocument.annotationStorage.setValue('FamilyName23412', { textContent: 'Test Surname' });
    pdfDocument.annotationStorage.setValue('GivenName23413', { textContent: 'TestName' });
    pdfDocument.annotationStorage.setValue('FamilyName23412', { value: 'Test Surname' });
    pdfDocument.annotationStorage.setValue('GivenName23413', { value: 'TestName' });
    pdfDocument.saveDocument();
    const pdfBlob = new Blob([await pdfDocument.getData()], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);

const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
downloadLink.href = pdfUrl;
downloadLink.download = 'downloaded.pdf';

// Automatically trigger the download by simulating a click
downloadLink.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the link
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();

URL.revokeObjectURL(pdfUrl);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to avoid this answer being misconstrued as negative, let me explain why this is not a simple task, with no single solution.

XFA is an XML based file with a PDF overlay, designed to be used in Adobe Reader using restricted inbuilt Acrobat Pro and Live Cycle editor code), thus not an ISO compatible PDF, the format was scheduled as NOT to be included in the PDF standard format (the one that PDF readers need to be able to comply with).

SO XML based PDF (as distinct from PDF with an imbedded XML file) is an Adobe Proprietary format generated purely by Adobe Servers in many different non published formats.

Several Readers provide a basic (or experimental) interface using the PDF Acroforms method to communicate with any simpler internal scripted XMP "static" data formats and there are several types. Formerly those produced in Live Cycle Servers and newer formats generated by Adobe Experience Manager (AEM).

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/forms/document-services/pdf-forms-and-documents.html

> "Adobe uses the term XFA PDF form to refer to the interactive and dynamic Forms you create with AEM Forms Designer. The Forms and files you create with Designer are based on Adobe’s XML Forms Architecture (XFA). In many ways, the XFA PDF file format is closer to an HTML file than it is to a traditional PDF file." ... Static Forms support font sub setting which is a technique that can be done on an AEM Forms Server. Static Forms can be rendered using the built-in PDF viewer that comes with modern browsers.
> **... NOTE
> Dynamic forms cannot be rendered using the in built pdf viewers of the modern browsers.**

Adobe and their [development partners](https://www.datalogics.com/how-to-flatten-xfa-pdf) suggest all XFA based pdf be simply "one way" converted to simpler plain PDF Acroforms  by "flattening".
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/edit-xfa-form.html

> Many recent browser versions have included their own limited support for XFA-based PDF forms. Although these browsers can **open** XFA-based PDF forms, the capabilities provided are limited.

Adobe guide for Firefox and Chromium based browsers is here https://helpx.adobe.com/livecycle/kb/xfa-forms-firefox-chrome.html

PDF.js *"PDF.js is a Portable Document Format (PDF) viewer that is built with HTML5."* does have **some limited access** for adjusting acroform data entries at very basic "static" xfa level and as HTML5 based some XML editing abilities however there are many related limits:-

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/13599 "only sees what user sees"
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/16937 "The pdf contains the form in two formats: XFA and Acroform. In the Acroform version, there is no callback behind the button Image de la signature and unfortunately **we render the Acroform one**."
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/16939 "Isn't this issue effectively a duplicate of the other one, since it seems that none of the AcroForm-fields have working scripting and you'd apparently need to use the XFA in order for this to actually work?
Opening the PDF document in PDFium (i.e. the Google Chrome PDF Viewer) it appears to be similarly "broken" there as well."

### The bottom line

Is either convert XFA with XDP data into a normal Acroform based PDF (there are many free and commercial PDF converters) or use Adobe AEM aware products from Adobe Reader and upwards to ensure best compatability.